# Facebook JavaScript not working on IE, but working on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api

My script below works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox but somehow doesn't work on IE. The code is to check whether the user is a fan of my page yet or not. The script neither redirect to another page (is a fan) nor show the likebox (not a fan).

Any idea? I'm very new to facebook application and javascript. Sorry for my noob.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Redirecting...please wait</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/js/all.js"></script>  
<style type="text/css">
  div#container_notlike, div#container_like {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    //if like botton click, reflesh page
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', 
        function(href, widget) {
        //alert("Like button clicked");
        window.location.reload();
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      var page_id = "PAGE_ID";
      if (response && response.authResponse) {
        var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        //var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
        FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
          if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
            console.log("LIKE");
            //alert ("Like");
            location.href="https://www.example.com/apps";


          } else {
            console.log("NO LIKEY");
            $('#container_notlike').show();

          }
        });
      } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response && response.authResponse) {
            var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
            FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                console.log("LIKE");
                //alert ("Like");
                location.href="https://www.example.com/apps";
              } else {
                console.log("NO LIKEY");
                $('#container_notlike').show();

              }
            });
          } else {
            console.log("NO LIKEY");
            $('#container_notlike').show();

          }
        }, {scope: 'user_likes'});
      }
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<center>
<div id="container_notlike">
          <fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/example" width="292" height="62" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="false" >
          </fb:like-box>

    </div>
</div>
</center>

<div id="container_like">
  YOU LIKE ME :)
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

FYI: I'm using IE9 and already update javascript to latest version. I've already opened javascript to run on IE9.

Comment: I find it interesting to see you updated JavaScript for IE

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my script, so i just give it a try to update the javascript.

Comment: Can you give some details of what's failing? Are you getting a JS error somewhere, and if so, what does it say?

Comment: You can't update JavaScript ;)

Comment: Try commenting out your console.log(); lines. IE has a habit of throwing a fit on console.log if developer tools arnt open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/js/all.js"></script>
```

If it's the FB SDK, try and remove that line.

Comment: It's work! May i ask why? I included that line intending for the script to load faster though.

Comment: Well, firstly it won't load faster. Putting all your scrips on the top of the page is often bad. They will block rendering until it's downloaded, so it's better to have them before the body closing tag.

Second, it was failing because at the bottom you were re-loading it asynchronously. When loaded twice the FB script is known to break in some ways, in this case, not working for IE.